# Workload deployment in GKE failing with error: Building the container image failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've built the docker image and pushed to github packages. I'm using GCP UI to deploy this image in an existing gke cluster.

All the options are default.

Repository provider, I'm choosing github from the drop down.

Image name GCP is autopopulating with `gcr.io/some-gcp-project/github.com/githubuser/cso:$SHORT_SHA` under filed image name.

Kubernetes deployment yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "cso"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "cso"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "cso"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "cso"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "cso-1"
        image: "gcr.io/some-gcp-project/github.com/githubuser/cso:$SHORT_SHA"
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "cso-hpa-o9ol"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "cso"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "cso"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "cpu"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

Any guidance on how to debug this?

Comment: Is there anything in `Deployment/Pod` events ? You say that you've built a docker image and pushed it to the registry, so as I understand you correctly, build stage was successfull and the problem occurs when you're trying to use such pushed image in your `Deployment` ? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Deployment itself is failing. So there is no Deployment/pod events. Note, I'm not using Google cloud registry instead pushing the docker image to Github. In GKE, you can pull images from from Github.

Comment: But if the `Deployment` is failing you should be able to get it `kubectl get deployment <failing_deployment_name>` and describe it `kubectl describe deployment <deployment_name>`. Really nothing in its events ? Is it a private GitHub repository ?